# What is an efficient way to get values that are not included in various arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
int[] a1 = {5,2,1,13,4,9,7};
int[] a2 = {3,1,6,9,23,12,34};
```

Now I want to get some values that are not included in either of the arrays, for example:
8,10,11,14,...

My current solution is to store the state (used/unused) of each possible value (approx 14000) in an additional boolean array. As soon as I use a value, it is marked in the additional array. So if I want to find values ​​that are not included in the other arrays, I just have to go through the additional array and look for values ​​that are not marked.

Is there another (efficient) way to get this done ?

Comment: Are all the values non-negative integers that are relatively small?

Comment: Don't use an array, use a `HashSet`.

Comment: Is there an upper and lower bound to the numbers you can have in these arrays?

Comment: Your current implementation is almost optimal, if memory consumption doesn't matter. Otherwise, use `BitSet` instead of boolean array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 performance aspects: the time of set construction from the given arrays and the time of getting the next not included value.

Also, there is memory usage aspect - if you have thousands of such independent sets, you would probably want the set data structure to consume as little memory as possible. (But I guess it isn't your case.)

Finally, typical number of not included values matters. I've tested 2 cases: a half of values are used and 99% of values are used.

I've benchmarked 3 solutions: your original boolean array, bitSet and HashSet.
https://gist.github.com/leventov/6749728
Results:

```
Benchmark                                   Mean    Units
construction_bitSet_05_load               19,184  usec/op
construction_bitSet_099_load              38,319  usec/op
construction_booleanArray_05_load          7,987  usec/op
construction_booleanArray_099_load        16,255  usec/op
construction_complementHashSet_05_load   859,151  usec/op
construction_complementHashSet_099_load  923,588  usec/op
construction_hashSet_05_load             262,920  usec/op
construction_hashSet_099_load            441,306  usec/op

nextIndex_bitSet_05_load                   2,086  nsec/op
nextIndex_bitSet_099_load                  2,147  nsec/op
nextIndex_booleanArray_05_load             9,264  nsec/op
nextIndex_booleanArray_099_load           65,424  nsec/op
nextIndex_complementHashSet_05_load       27,298  nsec/op
nextIndex_complementHashSet_099_load     142,565  nsec/op
nextIndex_hashSet_05_load                 27,159  nsec/op
nextIndex_hashSet_099_load              1948,120  nsec/op
```

(Complement HashSet is faster than ordinal in 99% load case, but is very expective on creation.)

Just as I personally expected, your original solution is fastest on set construction, and BitSet is fastest on the next not included value retrieval.

Memory consumption:

- `boolean[]`: 14000 bytes.
- `BitSet`: 1750 bytes (1 byte for each 8 possible values)
- `HashSet`: ~= 62 bytes per included value (~= 38 bytes with `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`)
- complement `HashSet`: analogously per *not* included value.

Answer (score 5):

Load the values into a `Set<Integer>` (once), then use `set.contains()`.

If you use a `HashSet`, the `contains()` method is O(1) - ie extremely fast.

Here's the code:

```
// Do this once
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : a1) set.add(i);
for (int i : a2) set.add(i);
```

then to check if a number is in it:

```
if (set.contains(i))
```

Or *not* in it:

```
if (!set.contains(i))
```

---

To get the first number, starting at 1, not in the arrays:

```
int i = 0;
while (set.contains(++i));
```

To find all numbers in a given range not in the set, as an array:

```
int[] arr = new int[max - min - set.size() - 1]; // correct final size
int index = 0;
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    if (!set.contains(i))
        arr[index++] = i;
```

Comment: @Kᴇʏsᴇʀ you don't need to reload every time you want to check if an integer is in the set.

Comment: @Kᴇʏsᴇʀ We need to find the values that are not contained in both the arrays, but the above Set will contain all unique elements in both the arrrays. i am not getting it, sorry :)

Comment: @PravatPanda I think OP meant "either" and not "both". Other parts of the question seem to confirm this.

Comment: @Kᴇʏsᴇʀ this approach is for "either".

Comment: @Bohemian I'm aware :p

Comment: Added some code you might find useful. Perhaps the downvoter will relent now.

Comment: @Bohemian I think you should delete this formulaic and misleading answer... `HashSet` is *the worst* solution in case of bouded range of possible values. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19074969/648955

Comment: @leventov HashSet is just fine. You're falling victim to premature optimization. As a starting implementation, I stand by this code. If after using this code, and a performance prpblem was suspected, and profiling *proved* this to be the culprit, only then would I consider implementing something else. HashSet is the goto set implementation and half the java code out there uses it profusely.

Comment: @Bohemian OP (user2089307) already has *faster* implementation that you suggested. And his question was "Is there another (efficient) way to get this done?". I think here on SO we shouldn't guess does someone really need optimization or not, did he spot the bottleneck correctly or not, and so on. Prematurity of optimization is the different question.

Answer (score 3):

If all the values are relatively small and non-negative, you can probably do well with a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

```
int[] a1 = {5,2,1,13,4,9,7};
int[] a2 = {3,1,6,9,23,12,34};
BitSet bits = new BitSet();
for (int i : a1) {
    bits.set(i);
}
for (int i : a2) {
    bits.set(i, !bits.get(i));
}
int[] result = new int[bits.cardinality()];
int next = 0;
for (int i = bits.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bits.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
    result[next++] = i;
}
```

This will probably be as fast as any solution using `Set<Integer>` and eliminates the autoboxing overhead associated with using the collections framework.

Comment: This answer is my second choice, +1

Answer (score 3):

If memory is no object and all that matters is performance ... and you know every possible value that **could** occur in your arrays ... then, sure, use a flag to indicate whether the value has been used.  This gives you fast testing, but as the number of unused values becomes small, generating a new one may take a long time if you are trying to generate them randomly.

If you know the range of values, why not fill up a container with all the possible values ... and then just randomize the order in the container.  When you need a value, just pop the 'next' one out of the container.  Using such a system:

- there's no need to test whether the value has already been used at all (because you already know that the container contains only one such value).
- generation of new values remains ultra-fast, no matter how many values have been used.

Another data structure that can help you to quickly determine whether a set of items already contains a particular item is to use a Bloom Filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), though it does not sound like such a filter would be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This method could be the most efficient by cpu and it uses zero memory. It requires modifying the initial data and is based on [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.

If you can't modify your arrays, you could clone them: `a1.clone()` and it would still be very efficient.

Method:

- sort both arrays
- use [Iterators.html#mergeSorted](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#mergeSorted%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to iterate over the merged sorted set of numbers.

Code:

```
Arrays.sort(a1);
Arrays.sort(a2);

Iterator<Integer> mergedIterator = Iterators.mergeSorted(Ints.asList(a1).iterator(), Ints.asList(a2).iterator());

... iterate to find gaps in the sorted sequence ...
```

It's time complexity is `O(n log(n))` and memory consumption is zero (constant). It could be faster if iterators didn't do boxing operations, like in Trove4j library.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use an ArrayList instead of the int[] then use the .contains(Object obj) function to see if the int value already exists in either array.

Comment: `ArrayList.contains()` is not better than just using a normal array and a `for` loop each time. In fact, it's the same (`ArrayList.contains()` is `O(n)`). If you want to base your implementation on `contains()` you should use a `HashSet` or `HashMap` because the lookup then is in constant time `O(1)`.